# Discord bot sends infinite messages when a user types a specific phrase

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I created a bot that, among other things, sends quotes from the garfielf video when someone in the chat says a specific phrase. For example, if I were to say "lasagna" it would respond with "*lasaga." However with one specific phrase it sends the message infinitely until I turn it off. It does this only when someone says "I hate " in the server. I've tried creating a channel variable equal to the returned value of client.get_channel(channel_id) and using channel.send() instead, but that has the same problem.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    lasaga = "lasagna"
    garfield = "garfielf"
    where_are_the = "where are the "
    wheres_the = "where\'s the "
    i_hate = "i hate "
    bad_bot = "bad bot"
    text = message.content.strip().lower()
    # sends response if keyword(s) are in message
    if lasaga in text:
        await message.channel.send('*lasaga')
    if garfield in text:
        await message.channel.send(f'I eat, {message.author.name}. It\'s what I do')
    if where_are_the in text or wheres_the in text:
        await message.channel.send('I eat those food')
    if i_hate in text:
        await message.channel.send('I hate alram clocks')
    if bad_bot in text:
        await message.channel.send('sowwy uwu')
```

I have no idea why this is happening with only one phrase.

Edit: this is the video: https://youtu.be/OGbhJjXl9Rk

Edit 2: it turns out the bot was triggering itself. I fixed it by setting bot_id to the bot's id and changing the offending if statement to this:

```
if i_hate in text and message.author.id != bot_id:
        await message.channel.send('I hate alram clocks')
```

Comment: When `"i hate "` is in the message you write a message to the channel that also contains `"i hate "`. Could it be that your bot is responding to its own message?

Answer (score 2):

The bot won't ignore it's own message, so if the bot writes it's own command it will execute it. This can be fixed by ignoring it's own messages as so

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    # the rest of your code goes here
```